# UIWebView redraw on rotate

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have implemented a UIWebView object into a custom UIView ([TSAlertView](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView&ei=lHGIUNPTK6OZ0QXu4YHQBA&usg=AFQjCNGGfcdwYzBRoxrc5fc3fjzdVqb7Qw)). My UIWebView sits in the middle of the UIView, as a subview.

When I rotate the iOS device screen, the UIWebView object redraws right on top of the old one, without deleting the old one. All the other elements of this custom UIView are destroyed and redrawn when the screen is rotated.

I imagine I must have missed some sort of procedure for deallocating resources or removing the UIWebView from view. I have tried adding 'autorelease' to the declaration of the UIWebView, but to no avail. I wonder if this is a common symptom of a simple oversight I have made in the way the UIWebView is created?

This seems to be a simple case of not telling the UIWebView object it should destroy itself before it is redrawn on each rotate - but I don't know how I can go about this...

Any wisdom gratefully received.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when the rotation happens? are you creating UIWebview again or just modifying the frame of the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally while rotating you should not create the views again. Instead you can rearrange the frame in delegates appropriately. In your case you might be creating a `UIWebView` again, which should be avoided. Instead of that, you can keep it as a class level param(Declare in .h file) and adjust the frame in delegate methods for rotation. Also please note that `release/autorelease` wont remove your view from superview. You need to call `removeFromSuperview` method to achieve that.

[Check this for view resizing and layout handling](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling)